# Convert input letter to different letter

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography

I am new to python (pardon my bad terminology). I cannot find a solution to my problem.

I am trying to make a **simple** encryption system. I want to convert the characters of user input to specific characters. For example: ABC would turn into ZYX.

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us what you've already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you just want a simple substitution cipher you can use the `translate` function:

```
# in python3:
# table = str.maketrans('ABC', 'ZYX')

# in python2:
from string import maketrans 
table = maketrans('ABC', 'ZYX')  # add the rest of the alphabet and the desired
                                 # subsitutions

print('CBA'.translate(table))
# output: 'XYZ'
```